# Este es el código de error que me aparece en visual studio:

Tags: python-3.x

Este es el código en donde se me genera el erro escrito en la pregunta:

```
" No name 'QApplication' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets'pylint(no-name-in-module)"
```

```
import sys
    from PyQt5 import uic
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
    #####################################################
    class mi_ejemplo(QMainWindow):

        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            uic.loadUi("ej4.ui", self)
            self.boton_d.setEnabled(False)
            self.boton_a.clicked.connect(self.fn_activar)
            self.boton_d.clicked.connect(self.fn_desactivar)

        def fn_activar(self):
            self.boton_d.setEnabled(True)
            self.boton_a.setEnabled(False)
            self.etiqueta.setText("ACTIVADO")

        def fn_desactivar(self):
            self.boton_d.setEnabled(False)
            self.boton_a.setEnabled(True)
            self.etiqueta.setText("DESACTIVADO")



    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        GUI = mi_ejemplo()
        GUI.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())'
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer, he descubierto el problema, Pylint doesn't load any C extensions by default, because those can run arbitrary code.así que descubrí que si crea un archivo de sistema en el directorio de su proyecto con el archivo llamado .pylintrcrc, puede incluir este paquete en la lista blanca para dejar de arrojar errores al agregar el siguiente código en el archivo rc extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5. Así que, esencialmente, el problema no es PyQt5, sino que el linter arrojó errores falsos debido a esto.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726580/no-name-qapplication-in-module-pyqt5-qtwidgets-error-in-pylint

Esa es la respuesta que resolvió el mismo problema que presentas, espero haberte servido de ayuda.